# Make an API request every minute and then process the results

Tags: c++, timer

I have a task to access an API every minute and get data. I call the API using the cpr library (which is based on libcurl)

```
cpr::Get(cpr::Url{ URL })
```

And store the data in a vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> myData;
```

How can I make these requests every minute (or whatever time interval I set with chrono)?

I would like to draw attention to the fact that I would like to somehow work with these data later (exclude duplicates for example).

In javascript I would write something like setinterval

Comment: Add a loop to call the method at appropriate time.

Comment: You can google: C++11 timer. Or use the timer in Boost.

Comment: Thanks for your support but could you write examples, I am not very good at c++ yet

Comment: About the Loop. In my application I will have an opengl loop, so I have to combine the two loops in some way

Comment: Hmm..., if you later want to drop the oldest values, a `deque` could be more appropriate than a`vector`